# DB URL to a Record? How-to?

Tags: database, http, url

Is it plausible to think we can access the contents of a database field or fields via a URL? For ie, can "http://dbms_node:port/database/tablename?query" work? I guess the limitation may be where we can specify the selectors? Can that be done via url fragments?

Comment: If someone implements this service

Answer (score 2):

If I am right in thinking  you are suggesting querying over a get this is a really bad idea due to the fact you would be opening up your database to malicious attack I could executet any query I liked upon your database. I really recommend not using this.

Answer (score 1):

While I am not aware of any DB offering such a service, the way of accessing content you describe is actually close to a web standard called "REST". ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer)).

Please pay attention to the answer by Deviland that this may be a huge security hole if not thought carefully.

Answer (score 1):

Unless whichever database software you're using comes with a service layer like this already, you could write some kind of a service that sits in front of that database to accomplish something *similar*.  Of course you'd want to be careful with regards to the security implications of allowing queries against your database through URL parameters and the like. (that's what the *similar* is for - and what Deviland is referencing)

Answer (score 1):

sounds like kind of couch db. 
http://couchdb.apache.org

googling `RESTful db connector` gives also some nice hints